# JBOSS/Keycloak cluster wait 1 minute before voting for coordinator

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I have 3 nodes keycloak cluster. If one node is down, JBOSS start coordinator selection in 1 minute. Is it possible to decrease this timeout, because of downtime? How can I config fail node detection timeout?

```
[root@keycloak-01 ~]# date; systemctl stop keycloak
Tue May 25 11:35:46 MSK 2021
```

```
11:36:58,629 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-43,ejb,keycloak-02) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [keycloak-02|24] (2) [keycloak-02, keycloak-03]
11:36:58,630 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread-43,ejb,keycloak-02) ISPN100001: Node keycloak-01 left the cluster
11:36:58,772 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=quartz] ISPN100007: After merge (or coordinator change), recovered members [keycloak-01, keycloak-02, keycloak-03] with topology id 104
11:36:58,774 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p7-t1) [Context=quartz] ISPN100008: Updating cache members list [keycloak-02, keycloak-03], topology id 105
11:36:58,808 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (non-blocking-thread--p15-t2) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [keycloak-02, keycloak-03], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 106
```

Answer (score 1):

I offer to pay more attention to 'Failure detection' (FD and FD_ALL) [in docs](http://www.jgroups.org/manual5/index.html#FD_ALL). I solved my task with the help of:

```
<protocol type="FD_ALL">
  <property name="timeout">5000</property>
  <property name="interval">3000</property>
  <property name="timeout_check_interval">2000</property>
</protocol>
```